# Laptop without battery resets BIOS when ac adaptor is removed

Tags: laptop, bios, power-supply, battery

I am using a dell inspiron 15 3537. Here's the thing:

If I remove the battery and try to power on, I get a constant beeping sound with screen showing nothing. After that I power it off clicking the power button for a few seconds. Then I press the power button again, it powers on and then, it shuts down and it turns on again by itself and it boots like it should. But after booting to windows, the date and time have been reset, and there's plenty of weird behaviour in the system like the function keys and multimedia button behaviour gets switched.

This happens every time the laptop loses its power source essentially and it seems that the BIOS is going to default settings.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you replaced the battery on the motherboard?

Comment: No, I have not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CMOS battery which is usually found on the motherboard is probably dead.

A laptop typically has up to three power sources:

- AC power
- High capacity re-chargeable battery
- CMOS backup battery

If all three power sources fail, there will be no power that is required to maintain the memory that stores your BIOS settings. Therefore all your BIOS settings will be lost and once you do provide power again, you will probably get warning tones telling you there was no power for the CMOS memory and settings were lost.

This will result in extended boot times while the system attempts to set up defaults again (by loading the defaults from a non-volatile memory store into the CMOS memory chip).

Identify the location of your CMOS backup battery and replace it with a new one.

Comment: I see. But the thing is that this was always the case for my laptop from the start of the purchase. Probably a defective CMOS battery?

Comment: Correct, it is possible it has always been faulty. If you replace it and there is still an issue, it is even possible the CMOS chip is faulty.

Comment: Can I replace this within my dell warranty?

Comment: If the CMOS chip were faulty, it would probably result in the motherboard being replaced.

Comment: I just called dell customer service and they suggested to update BIOS first.
After I did, alas there is no BIOS resetting. But the weird thing is that I still get the same beeping sound every time I unplug the AC charger.

Comment: Is there a pattern to the beeping? If so, look up BIOS or POST troubleshooting codes for your laptop model

Comment: The problem was eventually solved after DELL technician replaced all the motherboard. (CMOS battery was embedded to it)

Comment: Did the bios start resetting again, or was it just the beeping that was finally resolved?